# Oracle Datamodeler alternative for dmd files

Tags: oracle, dmd

i got a several problem with a Entity, relational and logical diagram that i made on oracle datamodeler, its work super slow, like 20 minutes waiting after change the size of a table, scroll down, or save the project.

I got a powerfull machine and i tested i anothers computers but still slow.

i got the 19,4 version.

Another program that can open dmd files? i cannot use draw.io or another program for create the diagram again from scratch, i have to send the dmd file, its for a project on my college.

Comment: Are you running any anti-virus software? Many of them cause significant problems for Java applications like the SQL Developer family. Try disabling the AV software or creating an exemption for Java and see if that helps.

Comment: nope, i dont use any anti virus, i have dissabled already the windows anti virus but still slow.